# Faulty Vim colorscheme within tmux, iterm, osx

Tags: vim, tmux

I am having trouble having my colorschemes display correctly when using terminal Vim (well, neovim but both seem to have trouble) within tmux.

I have setup iterm to report terminal type as `screen-256color`.
running `echo $TERM` in bash within iTerm expectantly yields `screen-256color`.
when entering tmux, running `echo $TERM` in iTerm yields `screen`.

Neither my `.bash_profile`, nor `.tmux.conf` files try to set the the `TERM` variable.  I have tried suggested solutions in other posts about it but they have not fixed it, e.g.
`alias tmux="TERM=screen-256color-bce tmux"` in my `.bash_profile`, and/or
`set -g default-terminal "xterm"` in my `.tmux.conf`

Though, from reading several other solutions it seems these are the 'wrong ways' to approach the problem, i.e. iTerm should be the one setting the `TERM` variable, and that the `TERM` variable should be set to `screen` for all programs running within tmux.

Here are some screenshots.
Without tmux

[image: without tmux]

with `set -g default-terminal "xterm"` or
with `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`

[image: with `set -g default-terminal "xterm"]

with `tmux` or `tmux -2` and `TERM` not being set anywhere

[image: with tmux]

It's probably also worth noting that I am using the [base16-eighties dark](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-vim) colorscheme for vim, and as recommended for base16 themes for terminal vim, I am using a base16 theme for iTerm ([base16-eighties.dark.256](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-iterm2)).  I am also on OSX.

**Update:** I have since tried updating the colorscheme for the terminal via the [base16-shell](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-shell) repository.  Running its `colortest` script file while in tmux seems to output perfectly, as shown in the image below

[image: base16-shell colortest output]

This was run with iTerm reporting `xterm-256color`, with a base16-eighties dark colorscheme, and tmux with the option `set-option -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` in `.tmux.conf`

I tried running again with the following vimrc (clean, no plugins, and the bare minimum to reproduce the images shown above)

```
set number " line numbers

if filereadable(expand("~/.vimrc_background"))
  let base16colorspace=256
  source ~/.vimrc_background
endif

" Theming
let base16colorspace=256
syntax enable
colorscheme base16-eighties
set background=dark
```

But it still looks like the last vim screenshot shown above.

Comment: I use `set-option -g default-terminal "screen-256color" ` in my tmux setup and outside is using `xterm-256color`
And I see no difference between tmux or non-tmux. 

I'm using iTerm 3.0.9/ base16 tomorrow-night theme in vim/neovim and base16-eighties dark in iTerm

Comment: I am on iTerm 3.0.9 as well.  With those settings I still obtain the strange coloring shown in the second screenshot (orange syntax highlighting became red, column/row highlighting becomes blindingly green).  I will have to investigate my plugins when I can find the time it seems